# Eclipse e4 tool Control in trimbars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to create combobox in trimbars.
So I started with adding a text box.

I created TrimBars->WindowTrim->Toolbar->Tool Control

I mentioned Class URI also

```java
public class SearchToolItem {

  @PostConstruct
  public void createControls(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    final Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Text text = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setMessage("Search");
    text.setToolTipText("search");
    System.out.println("i am in SearchToolItem ");


    GridData lGridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
    lGridData.widthHint = 200;
    text.setLayoutData(lGridData);

  }
}
```

I also put Sysout in method, but this method never gets executed.

I did same as mentioned in vogella site

see section 30.2
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#toolbar_advanced_toolcontrols

---

### Edited:-

@greg-449 
I have removed changing of parent layout,
below is the trimBars portion code of Application .e4xmi

```
<trimBars xmi:id="_MWSIoJgaEeKJoJcmiy2C6w" elementId="org.eclipse.emf.ecp.e4.application.trimbar.0">
  <children xsi:type="menu:ToolBar" xmi:id="_np7_0NHfEeSckszzmbNB_g" elementId="com.gide.sasm.application.toolbar.0">
    <children xsi:type="menu:ToolControl" xmi:id="_eGZ0ENHfEeSckszzmbNB_g" elementId="com.gide.sasm.application.toolcontrol.searchTool" accessibilityPhrase="" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.gide.sasm.cardprofile.model.viewmodel/com.gide.sasm.toolbar.handler.SearchToolItem"/>
  </children>
</trimBars>
```

After runnig application I can see trimBars but my text field is not present.
"To Be Rendered" and "visible" are set to true.
Is there some more entry needed, some where else also, am I missing something.

Comment: You should not be changing the layout of `parent` - remove the `parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());` line. Other than that it looks OK. Show us the declaration in the Application.e4xmi.

Comment: @greg-449 :- I have shared Application.e4xmi above.

Comment: Is 'com.gide.sasm.cardprofile.model.viewmodel' the id of the plugin containing your code?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, its a (.viewModel) generated by using EMF,
Class "SearchToolItem" lies in that module.

Comment: Are you specifying '-clearPersistedState' when you run the app? Without this new items are not picked up

Comment: @greg-449 Yes I have specified "clearPersistedState" to "true" in pulgin.xml

Comment: Try '-clearPersistedState' in program arguments in the Run Configuration

Comment: @greg-449 Can you please give me a working example for this, because I am trying everything but somehow its not working. :(

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me so I don't know what to suggest

Comment: greg-449 Thanks I got it running somehow,
But now the problem is that text box height is too small in trimbars, how shall I increase it.

Comment: Can you ask a new question about that so that any answer we come up with will help other people as well

Answer (score 1):

Your ToolControl have to be in the Window Trim, not in the ToolBar. 
[image]

Comment: If I have only TrimBars->WindowTrim->Tool Control
now I am not even seeing trimBars in the window. :(

Comment: There is no problem with having Tool Control objects in the Toolbar, I have apps with lots of these.

Comment: Did you checked if the toolcontrols are in the model on Runtime with a ApplicationModelSpy ?  Are there exceptions on Application Startup ?  Is bundleclass://com.gide.sasm.cardprofile.model.viewmodel/com.gide.sasm.toolbar.handler.SearchToolItem 100% right ?

Answer (score 0):

In my example, i implement a ComboBox to switch between perspectives. Here are the steps to follow.

1. Application.e4xmi:
   [image]
2. PerspectiveComboControl
   [image]
3. And here is how it lookalikes 
   [image]

I hope, this would help you.