# MPart toolbar too small for text ToolControl

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I added a search text ToolControl to a MPart toolbar as described here:
[Eclipse e4 tool Control in trimbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211033/eclipse-e4-tool-control-in-trimbars)
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#toolbar_advanced_toolcontrols

My problem is:
When I have another item (e.g. handled tool item with icon) in the toolbar, I can see most of the text, but not all. When there is no other item, I see just the upper line of the text.

The toolbar height seems not to be adapted to my control, [image: as in this image]

Whould be great if anyone can help me.

Christin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that although the `ToolBar` control allows controls as children it doesn't take their depth in to account when calculating the tool bar depth.

The Vogella example (which is intended for the window trim bar rather than a part tool bar) is using a default `GridLayout` which adds a margin above the search text. You could try using:

```java
Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
// GridLayout with no margins
comp.setLayout(GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().create());

Text text = new Text(comp, SWT.SEARCH | SWT.ICON_SEARCH | SWT.CANCEL | SWT.BORDER);
text.setMessage("Search");
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().hint(130, SWT.DEFAULT).applyTo(text);
```

That is using a `GridLayout` with no margins.

Comment: Thank you. It works, as long as there is another item defining the height. When the search text is the only control, I can see more now, but still far from all of the text. Do you have any idea how I can solve this? Adding an invisible additional item does not help.

Comment: My guess is you would have to do a custom part stack renderer.